# What could be causing my NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, tomcat7, drools, kie

I have an existing project with web services that I'm working to attach Drools to to process business rules on submissions to these services.

Everything seems to work fine in compile-time unit testing, but when I run the project in the Tomcat 7 container on my testing server, I'm getting the following stack trace:

```
05/25/2017 13:38:53.052 (EDT):[com.myproject.helpers.BusinessRuleHelper.checkBusinessRules]:[SEVERE]- Failed to process our request
05/25/2017 13:38:53.052 (EDT):[com.myproject.helpers.BusinessRuleHelper.checkBusinessRules]:[SEVERE]- Could not initialize class org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl
05/25/2017 13:38:53.052 (EDT):[com.myproject.helpers.BusinessRuleHelper.checkBusinessRules]:[SEVERE]- class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
05/25/2017 13:38:53.053 (EDT):[com.myproject.helpers.BusinessRuleHelper.checkBusinessRules]:[SEVERE]- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:135)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.getKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:101)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.getKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:79)
    at com.myproject.rules.Engine.processRequest(Engine.java:19)
    at com.myproject.helpers.BusinessRuleHelper.checkBusinessRules(BusinessRuleHelper.java:366)
    at com.myproject.helpers.BusinessRuleHelper.checkCriticalErrorBusinessRules(BusinessRuleHelper.java:291)
    at com.myproject.helpers.WebServiceHelper.processWebServiceRequest(WebServiceHelper.java:184)
    at com.myproject.webservicepackage.WebServiceImpl.webService(WebServiceImpl.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:172)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:63)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:74)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:123)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:206)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:213)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:193)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:127)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:187)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:110)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:193)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The last line frame under my control, in `com.myproject.rules.Engine.processRequest` is

```
/**
 * Runs a Request through the business rule engine
 * @param request The input to validate
 */
public static KieSession processRequest(Request request) {
    // load up the knowledge base
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer(); // <- Error happens here
    // This name matches the ksessionname of the rules knowledge base in the kmodule.xml file
    String kSessionName = "ksession-rules";
    KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession(kSessionName);

    // ...process the rules...
}
```

I'm confused, because the `com.myproject.webservicepackage` WAR file contains the Drools JARs in `WEB-INF\lib\` the way you would expect, and the last few frames are in the same library with the class that Java can't find the definition for.

The Drools JARs I see in the library folder are:

- drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar
- drools-core-6.5.0.Final.jar
- kie-api-6.5.0.Final.jar
- kie-internal-6.5.0.Final.jar

As far as I can tell, there's no overlap between these, and the first one is the library in question.

---

I've continued debugging this, and it looks like this is only the error encountered the second and subsequent requests. The first request came back with this stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type LoggerFactory; used in the signature
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:299)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.<clinit>(KieContainerImpl.java:92)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:135)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.getKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:101)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.getKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:79)
    at com.myproject.helpers.rules.Engine.processRequest(Engine.java:19)
    at com.myproject.helpers.BusinessRuleHelper.checkBusinessRules(BusinessRuleHelper.java:366)
    at com.myproject.helpers.BusinessRuleHelper.checkCriticalErrorBusinessRules(BusinessRuleHelper.java:291)
    at com.myproject.helpers.WebServiceHelper.processWebServiceRequest(WebServiceHelper.java:184)
    at com.myproject.webservicepackage.WebServiceImpl.webService(WebServiceImpl.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:172)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:88)
    ... 37 more
```

It looks like it's caching this failure as not having a class definition.

Comment: What's the full name of the jar drools-compiler*.jar?  Do you have more than one jar matching the pattern in your classpath? Do they all contain the missing file?

Comment: @laune, edited the question. There's only the one compiler JAR in the classpath.

Comment: I've looked at the source and it seems that you have a class loader issue.  Code in  KieServicesImpl calls org.drools.core.common.ProjectClassLoader.findParentClassLoader and I can't tell what this turns up. Does your code do anything that might affect the result of this call?

Comment: I don't think so, but I've read some FUD about things not working inside of Tomcat because of how it builds the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message:

> `java.lang.LinkageError`: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "`org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;`" the class loader of the current class, `org/slf4j/LoggerFactory`, and the class loader for resolved class, `org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder`, have different Class objects for the type `LoggerFactory`; used in the signature

...indicates a conflict between versions of SLF4J in my project. The library is being provided by some dependency I'm using and also by the Tomcat container itself. I used Maven to find what artifact is using SLF4J by running:

```sh
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.slf4j
```

This got me a dependency tree that shows where SLF4J is being used:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building business-rules 3.4-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ business-rules ---
[INFO] com.myproject:business-rules:jar:3.4-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.kie:kie-api:jar:6.5.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.drools:drools-core:jar:6.5.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.kie:kie-internal:jar:6.5.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- org.drools:drools-compiler:jar:6.5.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

I was able to remove the version brought in here by modifying the Maven POM for the project to exclude SLF4J in each of those three dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
      <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
      <version>${drools.version}</version>
      <exclusions> 
        <exclusion> 
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> 
        </exclusion> 
    </exclusions> 
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
      <version>${drools.version}</version>
      <exclusions> 
        <exclusion> 
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> 
        </exclusion> 
    </exclusions> 
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
      <version>${drools.version}</version>
      <exclusions> 
        <exclusion> 
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> 
        </exclusion> 
    </exclusions> 
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

And then in order to get it to build and test locally, I still had to add an explicit compile-time dependency on SLF4J in that same project, and also the one that imported it, to let Maven know that the Tomcat container will provide the dependency at runtime:

```xml
<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

These changes seem to have fixed my problems.